# Trouble getting datepicker in simple_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, simple-form

VIEW FILE

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "calender" %>
<%= simple_form_for(@obj, :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :created_at, :as=> 'datepicker' ,:label => 'Date of send' %>
<%end%>
```

CALENDER.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

When running ...getting error like

`No input found for datepicker`

when i remove . `:as => 'datepicker'` though calender doesnt come but it does not show error also. Kindly let me know whether I am doing correctly ?

Comment: try as: 'string' instead of as: 'datepicker'

Comment: <%= f.input :created_at, :as=> :rahul ,:label => 'Date of Smile', :default => Date.today %> , $("input.rahul").datepicker();                                                           Tried like this also , but no luck

Comment: replace the ":as=> :rahul" above with ":as => :string"

Comment: Hey its working... whatupp with string...can you please explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace this:
`<%= f.input :created_at, :as=> 'datepicker' ,:label => 'Date of send' %>`

with:

`<%= f.input :created_at, :as=> 'string' ,:label => 'Date of send', input_html: { class: 'datepicker' } %>`

---

explanation:

`f.input :created_at, :as=> 'datepicker'..` doesn't work because `simple_form` gem doesn't know about input of type `:datepicker`. And because the actual `datepicker` js library is designed to work with `input type="text"` you should just tell `simple_form` to use this kind of input with `as: 'string'`. Then the js library does it's part and transforms standart text input into a datepicker

Comment: Can you please tell ..why this 'string' only worked ?